# Operator precedence of ?? operator

Tags: php

I am a bit confused about the precedence of PHP's ?? operator.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php says that it has lower precedence than the / (division) operator. If that is true, `$a??1/0` should always give an error, not only if `$a` is `Null`, as it first evaluates `1/0`. As it doesn't give a "division by zero" error, I assume that the two sides of the `??` operator are evaluated as two different expressions and the second is only evaluated if the first yields `Null`. While it absolutely makes sense to implement it this way, doesn't this contradict the precedence stated on above page?

Comment: Judging by [Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) `??` works exactly as it should. Take a look at what `??` translates to and you will see why it doesn't give an error when `$a` is not null

Comment: `/` does indeed take precedence, but surely that would give `($a) or (error)` - which is what you say in the second half of your post, and does not contradict the precedence. It merely does the `1/0` part before the `is $a null` part.

Comment: I am well aware _how_ the two expressions are evaluated. My question stemmed from the fact, that this order of evaluation seems (to me) to contradict the stated operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

The null coalescing `??` operator will evaluate the right part of the expression **only** if the left part is Null.
This means it will evaluate the left part first in order to know if it is worth evaluating the right part.
See this as an optimisation of the interpreter to prevent executing some code if it does not reach it, and it doesn't look like an operator precedence issue.

Same in an if statement, when if (expression=true), the following elseif will not be evaluated.

Referring in the link you provided in the question, consider the following when you code:

> Use of parentheses, even when not strictly necessary, can often
> increase readability of the code by making grouping explicit rather
> than relying on the implicit operator precedence and associativity.

The example you provide

```
<?php

//$a=12;
$a=Null;
echo $a??1/0;
```

will really be parsed as:

```
<?php

//$a=12;
$a=Null;
echo ($a) ?? (1/0) ;
```

The extra parentheses will prevent the next developer that works on your code from getting it wrong.

Comment: I understand all that and it is basically what I said: "While it absolutely makes sense to implement it this way," (namely evaluating it as two different expressions (and the second one only, if the first gives "False")) my question was really in the second part of the sentence: "doesn't this contradict the precedence stated on above page?"

Comment: No, it does not contradict. The division operator takes over on the null coalescing operator. That is why 1/0 is evaluated as an expression, while the $a is evaluated as another one. In php doc : `The precedence of an operator specifies how "tightly" it binds two expressions together`. The precedence of operators does not define the order in which expressions are evaluated.

Comment: 1 is an "expression", 0 another one, and the operator / takes over on the ?? operator, so the 1/0 will become the new expression to evaluate. In this case, the / has no influence on the ?? operator, that will consider evaluation of "1/0" only if his rules are met ($a=Null).